# Why is information conservation not restricted by the uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, information, chaos-theory

The idea of information conservation seems to be: if all field equations/states of all particles/matter/waves at a certain time are known, all trajectories/waves can be backpropagated to retrieve all information.

Chaos- theory tells us, that trajectories may be very sensible to infinite small deviations of the position of a particle.
And the uncertainty means, that at a given point in time the energy (frequency) can not be measured, simply because to measure frequencies a time interval or more then 1 sample point in time is needed.
For a particle (matter wave), location and momentum can't be measured with infinite precision at the same time. Anyway it's a non-trivial (i.e., not a simple Dirac-function) probability function.

If information carrying particles are moving in complex ways for enough time, the precision which is needed to backpropagate the trajectories in order to retrieve the information should be at some time distance so great that it falls within the uncertainty ranges.

For example, a sequence of electrons is passing either slit A or slit B with very low time distance, given a fast binary sequence. The electrons are caught by a metal plate and this plate is - like all material - heated and vaporized during its trip into a black hole.

What ensures, that the information at a certain point in time  (in the example disclosed by a BH) is always given in a way/form/precision to calculate all complex trajectories (Fermi sea in the metal, bouncing in the compressed metal damp etc.) back to the binary sequence so that the uncertainty limits do not make it theoretically impossible?

Or does it only mean, that all information at a single point in time is generally not sufficient to get the information back?

Comment: My understanding of this is that the information is contained in the state vector of the system, and not in the measurements we make of it (which are limited by the uncertainty principle as you say). If we know the state at a given time then that deterministically evolves so information is conserved. Actually knowing the state is another matter.

Comment: @jacob1729. Yes, that is indeed what people mean when they say information is conserved. The trouble here is that a measurement is intrinsically probabilistic and creates a discontinuity in the unitary evolution, so as the OP states, there is no way to have the information back in a general sense.

Comment: A closed system evolves unitarily, and its information content is preserved in the sense that it is always possible (in principle) to completely reverse the evolution. The uncertainty principle is a statement about measurement outcomes/observables that can be produced by a system. But *measuring* a system necessarily implies making it interact with a larger environment, so that the evolution of the system itself is not unitary anymore, therefore not reversible. Does this address your question? (I'm not I understand what exactly you are asking)

Comment: But information is always some kind of resp. always involves measurement.
So information (even pure mathematics is measurement: thoughts, ideas, formulas are some kind of measurement of neuronal signals) is only conserved in principle,  but can't be retrieved in general. 
F.e. to know the state of a system at a given time means to measure the system at more then one single point of time (state vector measured for a single point in time is not sufficient in general).

Comment: Another example: the state vector of the complete universe may be unmeasurable since the measurement itself would be part of it, i.e. must be considered/measured itself. 
And of course, a free will is completely impossible if information is fully retrievable - we would only feel or think to have a free will.